# C# HTTP Listener ObjectDisposedException when retrieving requests asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, server, httplistener

I'm a beginner so please bear with me.

I've been trying to write a very simple C# HTTP Listener that can handle client requests asynchronously.

For that I used this sample code from the official Microsoft Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.begingetcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2

Even though I'm using the exact same code I keep getting an ObjectDisposed Exception. I can only fix it by manually waiting some milliseconds in the main thread, but this is a terrible solution that I want to fix, as it obviously slows everything down tremendously.

It seems like the main thread simply doesn't wait and closes the listener before the work is done, resulting in the object being disposed prematurely. I suppose that's why manually waiting fixes it. But why does the WaitOne() Method not wait?

To reduce personal errors I made my code almost identical to the sample, I only add the prefixes manually.

The Listener:

```
public static void NonblockingListener()
{
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/test/");
    listener.Start();

    IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback),listener);

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for request to be processed asyncronously.");
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("Request processed asyncronously.");

    // It will only work if I add this: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
    listener.Close();
}
```

The callback method:

```
public static void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener) result.AsyncState;  

    // It throws the exception at this line
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);

    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

    string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>";
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
    output.Close();
}
```

Finally, this is how I have my main function set up, it's only a simple infinite loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     while (true)
         NonblockingListener();
}
```

Am I being stupid or is it right to assume that there is something wrong with the sample code?
That would be weird but I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

If someone could maybe copy the same sample code and try running it, that would be great.

What would I have to change for it to work as intended?

Comment: `result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();` will return once `listener.EndGetContext(result);` returns - i.e. before you write to the output.

Comment: Try using `.Stop()` before `.Close()` - `.Stop()` is a much more graceful shutdown, and I'd expect it to wait until all requests have finished being processed.

Comment: Also, don't be too surprised when an example on MSDN has issues - some of them are of questionable quality

Comment: @canton7 If I replace ```.Close()``` with ```.Stop()``` or stop the listener before closing, it throws an invalid handle exception at this line: ```output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);```. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself after some more painful hours, I'll just post an answer here anyway in case someone has the same problem. The problem was that I kept closing and recreating the Listener instead of reusing it for the next request. This is a mistake I copied from the MSDN sample code page. It closes the Listener immediately after retrieving a client request, resulting in an error because the callback method can't access the closed Listener anymore to deal with the still running request.

The solution is to remove the loop in the main function and instead put an infinite loop around:

```
IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(newAsyncCallback(ListenerCallback),listener);
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

It seems obvious like that, but I guess I just took the MSDN for granted, which apparently is a mistake.